# Is there a function/plugin for line-by-line staging in atom.io?

Tags: git, plugins, atom-editor

On thing I really like about `eclipse` (and the 0.x version of `gitg`) is the possibility to stage changes line-by-line (see line 10 in the image below).

[image]

Is there plugin that allows this in the editor `atom.io`? (place old and new version next to each other, and allow to stage/revert the change)?

I installed the plugin `git-plus`, but this stages all changes for a given file,...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you can't find that feature you can do `git add -p` in a git console

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that interactive function of git. Having a GUI for that in atom.io would be great. I'm sure the is/will be one. RStudio also has this function: http://christianlemp.com/img/rstudio-git-init-7.PNG

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do directly from Atom, with the [`git-plus` package](https://atom.io/packages/git-plus) installed, once you have made two or more changes to a file far enough apart to be considered by git to be separate hunks then you can us the `Git Plus: Stage Hunk` command:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to open the [Command Palette](https://atom.io/packages/command-palette).
2. Start typing `Stage Hunk` until `Git Plus: Stage Hunk` is selected.
3. Select the file you want to stage a hunk from.
4. Select the hunk you want to stage, this will place a green tick next to it, select any additional hunks you want to stage in the same way.
5. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to stage the hunk(s).

I have created a little animation to demonstrate this:

[image: Git Plus: Stage Hunk]

Comment: Great explanation! And too bad it seems there's no tool like GitUp / Sourcetree / GitKraken etc, but integrated in Atom to avoid having one more program running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in `Atom ver.1.43.0`, there is a plug-in for `stage hunk` and `discard hunk` line-by-line. This plug-in is called `GitHub`. This allows user to `stage` or `unstage` the changes line-by-line. Here is screenshot:[image]

User has both options: Bulk staging and line-by-line staging. Also, `GitHub` provides platform to list the files that need to be staged and then, one can commit them with some commit-message. It's quite helpful.